# Calling a CMake function: number of arguments

Tags: cmake

There is a function named `myfunc` defined as

```
function (myfunc var1 var2 var3)
...
endfunction()
```

Then, I see a function call

```
myfunc(custom hahaha platform ALL
        COMMAND echo "hello world"
        SOURCES ${some_var} )
```

My question is

> The function `myfunc` takes 3 variables. **In the above function call, which are the 3 variables? Also, how can there be additional commands `COMMAND` and `SOURCES` within the function call?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

3 variables will be the first 3 arguments.

If your function was defined as follows:

```
function (myfunc var1 var2 var3)
  message ("var1: ${var1}")
  message ("var2: ${var2}")
  message ("var3: ${var3}")
  message ("number of arguments sent to function: ${ARGC}")
  message ("all function arguments:               ${ARGV}")
  message ("all arguments beyond defined:         ${ARGN}") 
endfunction()
```

after calling it as you stated:

```
set (some_var "some var")
myfunc(custom hahaha platform ALL
        COMMAND echo "hello world"
        SOURCES ${some_var} )
```

the outuput will be:

```
var1: custom
var2: hahaha
var3: platform
number of arguments sent to function: 9
all function arguments:               custom;hahaha;platform;ALL;COMMAND;echo;hello world;SOURCES;some var
all arguments beyond defined:         ALL;COMMAND;echo;hello world;SOURCES;some var
```

so you have called your function with 9 arguments, that are referenced with `${ARGV}`, all arguments that are not defined can also be referenced using variable `${ARGN}`.

Note that when calling function,  ALL, COMMAND, and SOURCES are just arguments to the function, nothing else.

In the end, here is the full documentation about [cmake functions and arguments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/function.html)

Answer (score 1):

To complement [@gordan.sikic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9233677/gordan-sikic) answer, you also might be interested in [cmake_parse_arguments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_parse_arguments.html) command.

It allows you to define named parameters to your function, like `COMMAND ...` and `WORKING_DIRECTORY ...` in `add_custom_command`. See example in the documentation page.